# QCalendarWidget - Reading background color of selected date

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside

I am trying to create a calendar that would toggle the color of a date on click. If the current background is white, set it to green. If it's green, set it to red. If it's red, set it back to white. However I do not know how to get the selection background color. Can anyone help please?

The stylesheet was set to get rid of that default selection color which blocks the color I want to show.

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import (QCalendarWidget, QApplication, QBrush)
from PySide.QtCore import Qt

class UserCalendar(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UserCalendar, self).__init__(parent)
        style = 'QTableView{selection-background-color: white;' \
                'selection-color: black;}'
        self.setStyleSheet(style)
        self.clicked.connect(self.onClick)

    def onClick(self, date):
        brush = QBrush()
        brush.setColor(Qt.green)
        charformat = self.dateTextFormat(date)
        charformat.setBackground(brush)
        self.setDateTextFormat(date, charformat)
        style = 'QTableView{selection-background-color: green;' \
                'selection-color: black;}'
        self.setStyleSheet(style)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    cal = UserCalendar()
    cal.show()
    cal.raise_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way that you have set a background color with `dateTextFormat(...)` you can get the color using `background()` that returns the `QBrush(...)`, then use its color(...) method . By default the color is black and not white as observed.

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import (QCalendarWidget, QApplication, QBrush, QColor)
from PySide.QtCore import Qt, Slot, QDate


class UserCalendar(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UserCalendar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.set_selection_color(QColor("white"))
        self.clicked.connect(self.onClick)

    @Slot(QDate)
    def onClick(self, date):
        color = self.get_next_color(date)
        charformat = self.dateTextFormat(date)
        charformat.setBackground(QBrush(color))
        self.setDateTextFormat(date, charformat)
        self.set_selection_color(color)

    def set_selection_color(self, color):
        style = 'QTableView{{selection-background-color: {color};' \
                'selection-color: black;}}'.format(color=color.name())
        self.setStyleSheet(style)

    def get_next_color(self, date):
        color = self.dateTextFormat(date).background().color()
        # by default background color is Qt.black
        if color in (QColor(Qt.black), QColor(Qt.white)) :
            return QColor(Qt.green)
        if color == QColor(Qt.green):
            return QColor(Qt.red)
        return QColor(Qt.white)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    cal = UserCalendar()
    cal.show()
    cal.raise_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you! May I ask what the @Slot do?